# PHP authentication and authorization

Tags: php, authentication, authorization

I've got a front controller which routes all the requests to their related Controller.

Now, I need to implement a structure like **USERS - ROLES - SERVICES**, where in Services I should put those things that the users can or cannot do (e.g. deleting a product).

`Users`, `Roles` and `Services` have to be persistent in db.

This is my **front controller** (`index.php`):

```
/* index.php is the front controller (something like a global controller
 * which routes all the requests to their relative controllers) */
require_once 'init.php';
require_once ROOT_DIR . "/controllers/DocumentController.php";
require_once ROOT_DIR . "/controllers/UserController.php";
require_once ROOT_DIR . "/resources/SMTemplate.php";

/* Pass an empty $contents array to the controller.
* The controller fills it with its contents and gives it back to the template. */
$contents = Array();

    $requestedUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parsedRequestedUrl = parse_url($requestedUrl,PHP_URL_PATH);
    $parsedRequestedUrl = strtolower($parsedRequestedUrl); // Lo mette tutto in minuscolo in modo tale da non avere problemi di case sensitiveness
    $uri1Parts = explode("/", $parsedRequestedUrl);

    if (isset($uri1Parts[3])){
        $controllerString = $uri1Parts[3];

        if (isset($uri1Parts[4])) {
            $methodString = $uri1Parts[4];
            // if ($methodString)
        } else {
            $methodString = '';
        }
    } else {
        $controllerString = '';
    }



switch ($controllerString) {

    case '':
        $controller = new DocumentController($contents);
        $template = $controller->goToIndex();
        $contents = $controller->getContents();
        break;

    case 'documents':
        $controller = new DocumentController($contents);
        switch ($methodString) {

            case '':
                $template = $controller->viewDocuments();
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;

            case 'documentslistforsharer':
                $template = $controller->documentslistforsharer();
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;

            case 'listdocumentsresponsegrid':
                $responseGrid = $controller->listDocumentsResponseGrid(); // in realtà ne esce un echo per ajax
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;

            case 'create_start':
                $template = $controller->createStart();
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;

            case 'create':
                $redirect = $controller->createDocument();
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 'users':
        $controller = new UserController($contents);
        switch ($methodString) {

            case '':
                $template = $controller->goToIndex();
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;

            case 'create_start':
                $template = $controller->createStart();
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;

            case 'create':
                $template = $controller->createUser();
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                break;

            case 'authenticate':
                $contents = $controller->getContents();
                $redirect = $controller->authenticateUser();
                //$template = $controller->authenticateUser();

                break;
        }
        break;
}

/* If the controller call returns a value in a $template variable, the front controller
* renders the template. If the value is returned in a $redirect variable, the front
* controller redirects the user to the url inside it. */

if (isset($template)) {
    $tpl = new SMTemplate();
    $tpl->render($template,$contents);
} elseif (isset($redirect)) {
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($redirect,PHP_URL_PATH);
    $urlParts = explode("/", $parsedUrl);
    $redirectMethod = $parts[4];
    // Checks if the fourth level of the url refers to the authenticate method or not.
    if ($redirectMethod == "authenticate") {
        header("Location: http://localhost/blabla");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("Location: " . $redirect);
        exit();
    }
}
```

How can I implement the **USERS - ROLES - SERVICES** structure?

Should I fill Services table in db with urls like "*documents/create*" and check if the user+role has got that service? I don't like it very much...I thought that authentication should have been done in specific Controllers, non in the front controller.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I think that like this, your question is too general to receive a satisfying answer. Have you checked the different strategies for access control? Here is a good link for a common one -en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control , check also the reference to `ACL` - Access Control Lists. Maybe check for some other too. When just pick one and ask more specific question about implementing what you've chose.

Comment: As for the concrete implementation - it's a little tricky - the easiest way is to create 3 tables - `Users`, `Roles`, `Services` and junction tables `UserRoles`, `UserServices`, `RoleServices`. But depending on how exactly your application will work maybe `UserServices` and `RoleServices` may get merged into only `RoleServices` if we assume that there won't be an user with unique access.

Comment: @Leron Thank you. The strategy I want to follow is that of role assignment: a subject can exercise a permission (concretely, accessing an url) only if the subject has been assigned a role. What I need is a suggestion about how to implement it in my application, if in the front controller or in different controllers, and how :)

Comment: Ok, then you don't need `UserServices` table. I prefer to implement the authentication on class level, which means to put all the logic inside the constructor of each controller, and check there if the user has permission to access the controller. You can do that by keeping information about the roles in a session variable. Also there must me already implemented modules for authorization/authentication (`Zend Framework` maybe has one, dunno) so it's a good idea to see how they made it exactly too.